# How to redirect from ngrx effects loginEffects to dashboard after login success

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-effects

I'm using ngrx and ngrx effects to implement my login system. The login service makes an api call and the the response is success OK. But user is not redirected to dashboard even though redux devtools shows a login success result as on image [image]

I just don't understand why redirection fails. This my ngrx loginEffect:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { catchError, map, of, switchMap, tap } from "rxjs";
import { CurrrentUserInterface } from "src/app/shared/types/currentUser.interface";
import { DashbaordComponent } from "../../dashbaord/dashbaord.component";
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";
import { loginAction, loginFailureAction, loginSuccessAction } from "../actions/login.actions";

export  class loginEffect {
    login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(loginAction), 
        switchMap(({request}) => {
            return this.authService.login(request).pipe(
                map((currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface) => {
                    return loginSuccessAction({currentUser})
               },
               tap(() =>this.router.navigate(['/DashbaordComponent']))),
        catchError(() => {
            return of(loginFailureAction())
        })
            )
        })
    ))

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}   
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the code editor, the **map()** is underlined, and when I hover that map() function then Visual Studio says "@deprecated — Use a closure instead of a thisArg. Signatures accepting a thisArg will be removed in v8".
It seems to me that the problem lies there. I need your help to understand why I'm not redirected to dashboard even though api call is success.

**EDIT BASED ON @AKOTECK'ANSWER**
After closing the missing parent on map() the errors are now on 'request' passed to the switchMap() as shown on the screenshot below:
[image]

And when I hover on the 'request' error, visual studio says:
" Argument of type '({ request }: { request: LoginRequestInterface; } & TypedAction<actionTypes.LOGIN>) => OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { request: LoginRequestInterface; } & TypedAction<actionTypes.LOGIN>, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
Type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.ts(2345) "
As on the sreenshot below:

[image]

But the request's value is coming from submit() function as in the snipet:

```
 onSubmit(): void {
      console.log('Submit', this.form.value, this.form.valid)
      const request: LoginRequestInterface = {
        user: this.form.value,

      }
      this.store.dispatch(loginAction({request}))
    }
```

I don't get what is wrong with the 'request' parameter there. Please your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using another switchMap insyead of tap

Comment: Yeah @Eldar vs code editor says the same thing on map(), when I change tap() to switchMap(). The real struggle is that I don't even know if the underlined map() in editor is the real problem about not redirecting after login success

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a syntax error. The closing parenthis from the `map` operator is missplaced.

```
return this.authService.login(request).pipe(
  map((currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface) => {
    return loginSuccessAction({currentUser})
  }), // <-- add the missing map closing parenthesis 
  tap(() =>this.router.navigate(['/DashbaordComponent'])), // <- remove the extra parenthesis from here
```

cheers

Comment: You're right, there was a missing parent. Thanks for having scrutinized the code that far. But a new error appeared when correcting the closing paren mistake, and I edited the question accordingly. Would you please take a look a it ? I appreaciate

Comment: You still have one too many closing parenthesis at the end of the `tap` line.

Comment: I just don't know how to tell you thank you. You saved my time.